# React dev tools complains about unminified version in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a website in production where the Chrome dev-tools say:

> This page is using an unminified build of React.

In my build process the webpack configuration is running the `production` flag `on`. My setup is:

```js
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
    }
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    mangle: false,
    beautify: false,
    sourcemap: false,
    comments: false,
    minimize: true,
    compress: {
      warnings: false,
      comparisons: false
    },
    output: {
      comments: false,
      ascii_only: true
    }
  })
]
```

I'm loading React inside my `.js` and `.jsx` files with `import`, **not** loading in the HTML with script tags pointing to `.min.js` files. Still the code is reduced in size, compared to the dev version.

What am I doing wrong? What is the reason for that warning?

My versions:

```
"react": "^15.4.2",
"react-dom": "^15.4.2",
"webpack": "^2.7.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trial and error setting `mangle: true,` turned off the warning.

I did not find information about this in the React docs, but it worked.

[React does suggest](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#webpack) running `UglifyJsPlugin` in its default configuration, which has `mangle` set to true by default:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
  }
}),
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
```